# How to set button title and image together when the UI is right to left?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, right-to-left, left-to-right

I have forced my app UI to right to left direction and vice versa based on the current language.

This is code to show title below image in `UIButton` when left to right is active (Default). So when I changed it to right to left, it doesn't working as it should be. Anyone here, can help me to make corrections to the existing one?

```
extension UIButton {
    func alignImageAndTitleVertically(padding: CGFloat = 6.0) {
        let imageSize: CGSize = imageView!.image!.size
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -imageSize.width, -(imageSize.height + padding), 0.0)
        let labelString = NSString(string: titleLabel!.text!)
        let titleSize = labelString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: titleLabel!.font])
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(titleSize.height + padding), 0.0, 0.0, -titleSize.width)
        let edgeOffset = abs(titleSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0;
        self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(edgeOffset, 0.0, edgeOffset, 0.0)
    }
}
```

Here's the one I'm using when the language is Arabic:

```
func alignImageAndTitleVerticallyWhenArabic(padding: CGFloat = 6.0) {
    let imageSize: CGSize = imageView!.image!.size
    titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -(imageSize.height + padding), -imageSize.width + padding)
    let labelString = NSString(string: titleLabel!.text!)
    let titleSize = labelString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: titleLabel!.font])
    self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-titleSize.width, 0.0, 0.0, padding)
    let edgeOffset = abs(titleSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0;
    self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(edgeOffset, 0.0, edgeOffset, 0.0)
}
```

**Notes**:

1. When I use the `alignImageAndTitleVerticallyWhenArabic` it comes below the button but the alignment is still not proper.
2. Arabic solution is working but button image is little stretching.